# StaleObjectStateException ERROR

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Anyone can point me to the error please?

Note: this is a simplified test case extracted from my real app.
Thus the weird usage of 3 entity managers and
em1.getTransaction().begin();
em1.clear();
em1.close();
at the end of each section.
In real app it happens in different times.
HibernateUtil is basically copied from the tutorial.

```
        HibernateUtil.open();

        EntityManager em1 = HibernateUtil.reserveEntityManager();
        em1.getTransaction().begin();
        StringType st1 = new StringType();
        st1.setName("a");
        em1.persist(st1);
        em1.getTransaction().commit();
        em1.getTransaction().begin();
        em1.clear();
        em1.close();

        EntityManager em2 = HibernateUtil.reserveEntityManager();
        em2.getTransaction().begin();
        StringType st2 = new StringType();
        st2.setName("a");
        st2.setId(st1.getId());
        em2.merge(st2);
        em2.getTransaction().commit();
        em2.getTransaction().begin();
        em2.clear();
        em2.close();

        EntityManager em3 = HibernateUtil.reserveEntityManager();
        em3.getTransaction().begin();
        StringType st3 = new StringType();
        st3.setName("a");
        st3.setId(st1.getId());
        [b]em3.merge(st3);[/b]
        em3.getTransaction().commit();
        em3.getTransaction().begin();
        em3.clear();
        em3.close();



public static EntityManager reserveEntityManager()
    {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

public static void open()
    {
        try
        {           
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("manager1");
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }
```

javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [WebOrganizer.classes.types.StringType#174]
   at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapStaleStateException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:646)
   at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:600)
   at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:237)
   at WebOrganizer.web.servlets.TypeServlet.test2(TypeServlet.java:356)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
   at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.invokeMethod(MethodHelper.java:580)
   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:517)
   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:669)
   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:956)
   at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
   at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:110)
   at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:720)
   at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:590)
   at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:484)
   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:332)
   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:327)
   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:299)
   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:204)
   at org.testng.TestNG.createAndRunSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:864)
   at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:830)
   at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:748)
   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:73)
   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:124)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
   at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:90)

Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [WebOrganizer.classes.types.StringType#174]
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:261)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:120)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:53)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:677)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:661)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:665)
   at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:228)
   ... 28 more

Answer (score 1):

I'd give something like this a try:

```
EntityTransaction tx1 = em1.getTransaction();
// make your modifications
em1.merge(st1);
tx1.commit();
```

Not sure why you have are beginning a transaction right before you clean up the EntityManager.  I don't work with JPA transactions programmatically so this is just an educated guess.  Also, why are you creating a new EntityManager every time if it's returning the same instance?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you saving middle state of objects? If you must, try another approach. Pass on the identifier making sure  you start the transaction right before the `get` and `flush` right after.

Remember thou, that it is better to flush the session than call commit. Since flush actually performs a write in the database so you don't need to call close.